# How To Return A Variable From An AJAX Call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Just a simple question (I think).

Have a look at the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9wdM/1/

What I doing is creating a website as a personal project that let's the user enter any amount of names and e-mail addresses and once the form is submitted, a random name is selected from the names and an e-mail is sent to that person and also their name is outputted on the page.

I can get the AJAX call to work but I don't know how to pass the name variable back from process.php to index.php as all it can return is a 1.

I hope that makes sense, if it doens't please let me know and I will try and make it clearer.

Thanks again,

Martin

Comment: From what I can tell, what you're doing is correct.. What I don't understand is why you only get a 1 from your process.php.. Every "echo" should be returned to your ajax's onSuccess handler..

Comment: really? I always thought that you could only echo one thing from an ajax request? Maybe I'm very misinformed then. It's just that if I echo anything else back at all then the error is thrown as if a 0 is returned.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - been too long since i worked with PHP. Yes, you can only echo 1 ting - but it can be whatever... HTML, JSON, whatever you can handle in both ends of your request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it, changed the ajax call to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.tearoundform').submit(function() 
        {
             var query = $(this).serialize();
             $('#form_results').fadeOut(500).addClass('ajax-loading');
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "process.php",
                 data: query,
                 success: function(data)
                 {
                      $('#form_results').removeClass('ajax-loading').html(data).fadeIn(500);
                 }
             });
        return false;
       });
    });
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code your are misssing dataType which means the type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

So in your case you can set dataType as html and render html from server.
[This](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest u one thing if u want something return from ajax page then must use **dataType='json'**

and use `json_encode(array('returnData'=>1))`on **process.php**

again on **index.php** u can use `json_decode()`

[Reference](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/08/15/jquery-json-with-php-json_encode-and-json_decode/)
[dataType='json'](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types)

Comment: one Good Tutorails is [Here](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-json-jquery-ajax-screencast)

Comment: thanks all but I'm starting to feel a bit confused, sorry for being stupid! What I have in process.php at the moment is `echo json_encode(array('returnData'=>1))
        echo "<div class=\"done\">$nominee</div>";
        echo $result; ` and in the JS file ` dataType: 'json'` and nothing new added to the index.php page.

I think if I can solve this then I'll know a lot more about AJAX

Comment: @martincarlin87 **Note:** the page where you write `echo json_encode()`( in your case it is `process.php` ) strictly does not send anything to the browser..means there is no **echo** no `print` etc..on `process.php`.bcoz that page goes to the process in `ajax`

Comment: I see, so do you have any ideas how to return the `$nominee` variable to the javascript file?